# Paypal API for codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I need a paypal library for codeigniter (without redirecting to paypal site), I used angell eye paypal library but it had some issues.

If you have any suggestion which library should i use but i dont want to redirect to paypal site. I have Username, password and signature.

this is my code

```
$params = array(
'amount' => 100.00,
'currency' => 'USD',
'return_url' => 'https://www.example.com/checkout/payment_return/123',
'cancel_url' => 'https://www.example.com/checkout');



$this->load->library('merchant');
$this->merchant->load('paypal_pro');
$this->load->helper('language');

$settings = array(
'username' => 'sandbo_1215254764_biz_api1.angelleye.com',
'password' => '1215254774',
'signature' => 'AiKZhEEPLJjSIccz.2M.tbyW5YFwAb6E3l6my.pY9br1z2qxKx96W18v',
'test_mode' => true);

$this->merchant->initialize($settings);

$response = $this->merchant->purchase_return($params);
print"<pre>";
print_r($response);die;
```

Thank You

Comment: If your issue is resolved. try to add/accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try [CI-Merchant](http://ci-merchant.org/) payments API

In that you need to use PayPal Website Payments Pro

**EDIT:**

```
$this->load->library('merchant');
$this->merchant->load('paypal_pro');
```

Express check out will take you to Paypal site for payment. Paypal pro will process payments in your server.

** Make sure you are running the code in **test/production server**(public accessible) but **not local machine**

Comment: I tested it at production server.